# How can I access the console of a booting EC2 instance in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, linux

I'm new to AWS and am looking for a way to access my EC2's console so I can triage issues such:

- boot to single user mode
- view console output as system boots
- gain console access to debug GRUB issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Background

When using cloud services such as AWS or Azure your ability to access the console of booting instances is typically restricted to a read-only type of interaction.

AWS does provide tools, so you just need to adjust your approach, if you're expecting to drop to single user mode or watch a booting system on a console.

For example, in the EC2 services area of AWS you can select a EC2 instance and then under the actions menu select either:

- Get System Log
- Get Instance Screenshot

#### Example

**Step 1: Screenshot of actions menu**

[image: ss#1]

**Step 2: Screenshot of "System Log"**

[image: ss#2]

**Step 3: Screenshot of "instance's console"**

[image: ss#3]